# Body Class Being Applied How To Use?

Tags: css, drupal

Hello i have noticed on my theme that i seem to be getting some kind of body class (??) applied whe i enter a 'section' of my drupal website.

[image: firebug css]

I have no way of knowing how to use this. Could anyone explain more fully to me? thanks

I have tried this so far but with no effect-

```
    body.science {
background: none repeat scroll 0 0 yellow;
}

body.science a:link {
color:blue;
```

}

Comment: sorry you can view my website in more detail here- http://onlinebanter.com/science thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On line 28 you have a style defined (remove that part about `a` and you will be fine):

```
<style type="text/css">
    a:link, a:visited {
        color:#242424
    }
    a:hover {
        color:#CD2A2A
    }
    a:active, a.active, li a.active {
        color:#CD2A2A
    }
</style>
```

Comment: Sorry Antony is this a good or a bad thing for me? lol Is this what is stopping my code above from working? Is the code that i posted correct? I will go see if i can locate that inline style as there is a lot of stuff going on without my knowledge with this theme it seems.

Comment: ps if i do have seprate body classes for each of of sections then thats fine with me as i would like to change the body and ln colour to suit each term.

Comment: This style is defined below all your other stylesheets. The CSS defined last takes effect.

Comment: Thanks Antony. It seems that my themes inbuilt color picker is overriding things and adding these styles. Im am currently trying to find out how to remove this fromt he theme. Hopefully i shoudlnt be too long :hope tx